# Java method to check consecutive numbers

Tags: java

I need to write a method called consecutive which takes in 6 parameters to check if the 6 inputs are consecutive numbers regardless of order. If the numbers are consecutive, it returns a true, otherwise false. Can someone teach me what is the most efficient way of doing so? I tried this method but it would be inefficient if i have 6 numbers ?

```
public static boolean consecutive(int numberOne,int numberTwo,int numberThree) {
    if(((numberTwo==numberOne-1) && (numberThree== numberTwo-1)) || ((numberTwo==numberOne+1) && (numberThree==numberTwo+1)) || ((numberTwo==numberOne+2) &&( numberThree==numberOne+1)) || ((numberTwo==numberOne-1)&& (numberThree==numberOne+1)) || ((numberTwo==numberOne-2) && (numberThree==numberOne-1)) ||((numberTwo==numberOne+1) && (numberThree==numberOne-1))){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Can you show us what all you tried in "consecutive" methods.

Comment: What I have tried could not work. Furthermore, I do not even know how to rearrange the numbers into sequence because I am just a week into java.

Comment: Why should we do your homework? Do you really think this will help you later?

Comment: the one above is the code for 3 numbers but it would be inefficient if i have 6 numbers using if condition?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the values to an array, sort the array, then test for a sequential set of values:

```
int[] test = new int[] {numberOne, numberTwo, etc...};
Arrays.sort(test);
for (int i = 0; i < test.length - 1; i++) {
  if (test[i] + 1 != test[i + 1]) {
    // Not sequential
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you chris! that is really helpful! However, could you suggest how i could do this purely using loops and if statements?

Comment: If you have to implement it yourself, look up bubble sorts, a nice simple algorithm for sorting.

Comment: Thank you chris! I tried a method but it would be inefficient if i have 6 numbers?

Comment: Six numbers would be fine, it will be inefficient when you have hundreds of numbers to test, but six will take less than a millisecond. :)

Comment: public static boolean consecutive(int numberOne,int numberTwo,int numberThree) {
    if(((numberTwo==numberOne-1) && (numberThree== numberTwo-1)) || ((numberTwo==numberOne+1) && (numberThree==numberTwo+1)) || ((numberTwo==numberOne+2) &&( numberThree==numberOne+1)) || ((numberTwo==numberOne-1)&& (numberThree==numberOne+1)) || ((numberTwo==numberOne-2) && (numberThree==numberOne-1)) ||((numberTwo==numberOne+1) && (numberThree==numberOne-1))){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

Comment: the one above is my code for 3 numbers but this would be inefficent for 6 numbers?

Comment: Look at the code above, where I put the values in an array, then how I test each value in the array against the next in the loop.  This is what you need to do too.

Comment: but im not suppose to use array? Is there any other way by using if else?

Comment: Have a look at lists.

Answer (score 1):

Enhancing @Chris's answer, assuming there are no duplicate numbers:

```
public static boolean consecutive(
  int numberOne,int numberTwo,int numberThree, 
  int numberFour, int numberFive, int numberSix) {

 int [] ns = { 
   numberOne, numberTwo, numberThree, 
   numberFour, numberFive, numberSix };

 Arrays.sort(ns);

 return ( ns[ns.length-1] - ns[0] == ns.length-1 );
}
```

Comment: That would not work if there were duplicates and gaps like so:
1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6

Comment: True, I've noted it in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: In fact this answer only checks if the highest and lowest numbers differ by exactly the array length - 1.